# How to input a capital letter by using "solo.sendkey()"?

Tags: robotium, instrumentation

I'm using [Robotium](http://robotium.com/) to test my Android app. In a `webView`, I need input a capital letter by `solo.sendkey()`. But, I found there are only lowercases in `KeyEvent.KEYCODE`s.

I tried to use `this.getInstrumentation.senKeySync()`; but, it is no use.

Can I input capital letter by `solo.sendkey()`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with modifier key: KEYCODE_CAPS_LOCK?
There are two more options: 1) KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT and 2) KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT.

Ideally, sending the KEYCODE_CAPS_LOCK keyEvent first should help to you send capital letter in the second event.
You can find more details about KeyEvents here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html